# Submitting a hidden form in Angular4

Tags: angular, forms, http, hidden, same-origin-policy

To overcome a CORS (cross origin request sharing) problem I am facing with submitting a regular HTTP request, I need to submit a hidden form in Angular 4. I did that in HTML with no problem. However, I am not sure how to do that in Angular. 
Here is the code I have in the html of my component:

```
  <form form #f="ngForm" action="https://whatever.site.I_access" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="openid email">
   <input type="hidden" name="response_type" value="id_token token">
   <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="myClientId">
   <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="https://my.redirect.com/">
   <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="aNonceValue"> 

   <button type="submit" (click)="f.submit()">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

In my .ts file, I have implemented the function "submit". By leaving it empty, the form is not submitted. What is the command to write inside this function just to submit the form with the specified action?

```
 onSubmit(){
 console.log("form submitted");
 }
```

Any clues?

Comment: Instead of `<form form #f="ngForm" ...>` use `<form ngNoForm" ...`, and it shouldn't need to call `f.submit()`

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/592792/andré-werlang can you please put your comment as an answer and make it more clear as I do not really understand what you mean. I am really new to Angular 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the form is attached to the document, it should work:

```
  <form #form ngNoForm action="https://whatever.site.I_access" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="openid email">
   <input type="hidden" name="response_type" value="id_token token">
   <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="myClientId">
   <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="https://my.redirect.com/">
   <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="aNonceValue"> 

   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

This will make angular ignore the form, so it will be a plain HTML form. The button will trigger its submission.

To submit the form programatically, on the component get hold of the form. `form` below refers to `#form` above. `nativeElement` refers to `HTMLFormElement`.

```
 import { ..., ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
 ...
 @ViewChild('form') form: ElementRef;
 ...
 submitForm() {
   this.form.nativeElement.submit();
 }
```

Then call `submitForm()` whenever needed.

Comment: Thanks Andre, this solved my problem. You saved my day!  Now, just a tiny more thing, is it possible, so submit the form without clicking on submit. I want everything to be hidden in the background.

Comment: After the HTTP request is executed successfully and a response is returned. I need to read the response and do some processing. Do you have a useful link on how to do that or give me some useful hints?

Comment: This can't be accomplished by a form. This is because when a form is submitted, the context is destroyed and a new one gets loaded. Even if there was a callback when the form completed submission, there would be no time do do anything. The submit event happens before the form is actually posted. So I'd say look into JSONP. You'll make a get request that will return a javascript payload, that will call a function by a name you specify. Of course the backend needs to support it.

Comment: How to receive in component Form Data submitted to "https://whatever.site.I_access" considering whatever.site is in angular ?

Comment: @mayank it seems you need to perform an Ajax/http request. There's plenty of info on that on SO already.

Comment: @André Werlang , I am redirecting from one angular app to another one using  As I need data at secondAngularApp which I do not want to send in URL as query string so I am sending it as in form of hidden inputs form submit which post data to external url. My question is how to receive the same data at second angular app init component as I can already see data posted in Form data?

Comment: @mayank comments are for clarification. you have an entirely different problem, so post as a separate question with the code you have so far. you'll get an answer faster as more people will see your post.